Short story about a town that kills one of their own citizens by bombarding him with hateful thoughts
I recall a short story I read around 1990-1998, probably in some collection like The Year's Best Science Fiction & Fantasy, that ends with the townspeople forming a circle around one of the townies, and collectively channeling hatred at the townie so hard that he/she starts to bleed (perhaps out of the nose and ears?), collapses, and dies.
There's also a chance I'm conflating The Lottery with a beat from some other short story, however.

This sounds very familiar, but I'm not placing it.

Yes, this has come up before. If there isn't a dupe on here, then I saw it on another forum like sffchronicles.

Thanks—this helped me find it right away!

Found it, thanks to @cassfrank, via https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/580816/!
It's "The Public Hating" by Steve Allen: https://paperbackdesign.com/the-public-hating-by-steve-allen/
Thank you!

Don't forget to accept in two days!
